# Terminal middleware (api key check) not working with endpoint routing

Tags: c#, .net-core, api-key, asp.net-core-routing

I am implementing an api where on one specific POST route there must be an API key check.

The SDK is dotnet core 3.1.

When I run the API using Postman, I get the following error:

> *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints*

I looks like the route attribute on the api controller, together with endpoint route registration are stacked...

How can this be fixed ?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger(Configuration);

    app.UseRouting();    

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
           endpoints.MapApiKeyAuthentication();
           endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

(extension class)

```
public static IEndpointRouteBuilder MapApiKeyAuthentication(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
{
    endpoints.MapPost("/v1/xyz", endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder()
           .UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>()
           .Build())
           .WithDisplayName("ApiKey");

    return endpoints;
}
```

Comment: What URL do you test it with in postman

Comment: Local test in Visual Studio 2019: 

https://localhost:44353/v1/xyz

with post body and authorization header